# Design bug on the new badge page

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges, design, help-center

I found a bug on the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) in the new help center. If the question name is too long, it's not possible to see who has earned the badge. See for example for the [Announcer Badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer):

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were going to do a slight redesign of this page, which renders this bug obsolete.

Comment: So it's [status-declined]?

Comment: For lack of a better term, yes.

Comment: We need a [status-wontfix] tag.